# Parsing inconsitent json structure

Tags: json, go, duckling

I am using [duckling](https://github.com/facebook/duckling) as a tool for date/time and unit extraction. When I send a request like `today`, I am getting (some fields have  been removed for readability):

```
{"body":"today", "value": {"value":"2019-08-10T00:00:00.000-07:00", "grain":"day", "type":"value"}, "dim":"time"}
```

Thus, I created these structs:

```
type DucklingEntry struct {
    Body string `json:"body"`
    Dim string `json:"dim"`
    Value DucklingValue `json:"value"`
}

type DucklingValue struct {
    Value string `json:"value"`
    Grain string `json:"grain"`
    Type string `json:"type"`
}
```

When I send a request with the text value `6 euro`, I am getting:

```
{"body":"6 euro", "value": {"value":6, "type":"value", "unit":"EUR"}, "dim":"amount-of-money"}
```

As you can see, the inner `value` field now contains an integer instead of a string. When I parse the json string using the shown struct, the inner `value` value will be `""`.

How can I account for such an inconsistent json response?

Comment: Since you're making two different requests and getting two different responses you should have two different structs, now you don't have to if you don't want to, but that's the most sensible approach in my opinion.

Comment: ... if you decide you want to stuff the two separate response types into a single struct type you can use the `json.Number` type. https://play.golang.com/p/Uvo6-awBs1L